# How can I make this 'click-gallery' jQuery code better?

Tags: jquery

Following is crude way that I could think of to implement a click-gallery. I know there are better ways to do so that doesn't require binding `click` with every button.

What I am looking for: Anyway through which I can guess which button (span in this case) was clicked. And bind it automatically.

Thanks. Here's code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#gallery-button-1').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/koala.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-2').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/lighthouse.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-3').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/penguins.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-4').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/tulips.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-5').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/5.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-6').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/6.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-7').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/7.png)");
        });
        $('#gallery-button-8').click(function () {
            $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(Content/images/8.png)");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="Gallery">

    <div id="ButtonBox">
        <span id="gallery-button-1">1</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-2">2</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-3">3</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-4">4</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-5">5</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-6">6</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-7">7</span>
        <span id="gallery-button-8">8</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Image"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 `data` attributes to simplify this greatly:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ButtonBox span').on('click', function() {
    $('#Image').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data('image') + ')');
  });
});
```

And your modified HTML:

```
<span id="gallery-button-1" data-image="Content/images/koala.png">1</span>
...
```

---

A more compact solution with an array:

```
$(function() {
  var images = [
    'Content/images/koala.png',
    ...
  ];

  $.each(images, function(index, value) {
    $('<span />').text(index + 1).appendTo('#ButtonBox');
  });

  $('#ButtonBox').on('span', 'click', function() {
    $('#Image').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[$(this).index()] + ')');
  });
});
```

Now you can remove all the `<span>` elements.

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'** should I get latest jQuery version?

Comment: Yep. You probably figured it out by now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```
$('span[id^="gallery-button"]').click(function() {
    var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
    var buttonNum = currentID.substring(currentID.length - 1);
    var imgURL = 'Content/images/' + buttonNum + '.png';
    $('#Image').css("background-image", "url(" + imgURL + ")");
});
```

Of course this only works with numbered images. To get other images you need to find a way to include that in your markup as suggested with the data property above.

Comment: in your `.css` line, shouldn't there be a closing bracket in the end?

Comment: Yes, I just typed it out really quickly. I fixed it.